# How to verify if my OpenSSL version is vulnerable to CVE-2016-7056 (ECDSA P-256 Key Recovery Timing Attack)

Tags: openssl, cve

The application I am testing has the OpenSSL " 1.0.1e-fips" version on it.

I came across this vulnerability CVE-2016-7056 (ECDSA P-256 Key Recovery Timing Attack) and could not find a way to verify if our OpenSSL is vulnerable to this attack.I am curious to know about the way/steps to verify this vulnerability for our application.

Answer (score 1):

Check your open ssl version
openssl 
--version

### Below are the list of affected versions.

Versions Affected:
OpenSSL 1.0.1u and previous versions
LibreSSL (pre 6.0 errata 16, pre 5.9 errata 33)
BoringSSL pre November 2015

Mitigation:
Users of OpenSSL with the affected versions should apply
the patch available in the manuscript at [1].

Users of LibreSSL should apply the official patch from OpenBSD [2,3].

Users of BoringSSL should upgrade to a more recent version.

Comment: This is not answering the question how to verify wether that specific build is vulnerable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really willing to break your neck reading lot of stuff you may find a way to PoC the CVE based on what is written on this whitepaper:

- [Timing and Lattice Attacks on a Remote ECDSA OpenSSL Server: How
  Practical Are They Really?](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/839.pdf)

and this discussion on Seclists:

- [CVE-2016-7056 ECDSA P-256 timing attack key recovery (OpenSSL, LibreSSL, BoringSSL)](http://seclists.org/oss-sec/2017/q1/52)

Good luck